# if RecyclerView cant cover a full screen, the CoordinatorLayout will not work?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fragment.background">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/fragment.background"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/fragment.background"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/merchantHintText"
                    android:id="@+id/contract_template_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:padding="15dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:src="@color/fragment.background" />

                <com.tqmall.salestool.merchant.task.UploadImgLayout
                    android:id="@+id/contract_template_imglayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="15dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contract_template_info"
                    style="@style/merchantHintText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:padding="15dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:src="@color/fragment.background" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <com.tqmall.salestool.view.ListRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/contract_template_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contract_template_sure_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/text.red"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When my adapter have enough number of data (which inflating a much higher view than screen), the LinearLayout in AppBarLayout will collapse correctly. However, if there are few data, it will not collapse. I read the source code of AppBarLayout, but not find the code cause that.

Why it acts like that?

Comment: By design, I think. It's not broken.

Answer (score 0):

Just put you Linear layout into CollapsingToolbarLayout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <!-- views -->
            </LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/scrollableView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Try this. It should work.